# div floats to next line

Tags: html, css

I have a prototype lightbox that will float the second element if the text within it exceeds 28 characters. What am I doing wrong??

This is my current **CSS** and **HTML**

```css
    

// Parent Div
.lightbox-item {
  z-index: 8200;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 650px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}
// First Child div
.lightbox-item .avatarBox {
  height: 155px;
  width: 155px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  background: green;
}
// Second Child div
.lightbox-item .infoBox {
  padding: 10px 5px 0 0;
  height: auto
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  background: orange;
}
// Third Child div
.lightbox-item .person-info-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  height: auto;
  clear: left;
}

// Secondary elements nested inside 2nd & 3rd Child div
.lightbox-item .infoBox .gallery-member_fullname{margin: 0 auto;line-height:1em;text-align:left;}
.lightbox-item .infoBox .gallery-member_title{margin: 0 auto;line-height:1em;text-align:left;}
.lightbox-item .infoBox .gallery-member_company{margin: 0 auto;line-height:1em;text-align:left;}
.lightbox-item .infoBox .gallery-company_location{margin: 0 auto;line-height:1em;text-align:left;}

.lightbox-item .person-info {
  padding: 10px 0 25px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 275px;
}

.lightbox-item .person-info h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
      <div class="lightbox-item" style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -224.5, -226);">
      <div class="avatarBox"></div>
      <div class="infoBox">
        <h2 class="gallery-member_fullname">Bill Gates</h2>
        <div class="gallery-member_title">Founder</div>
        <div class="gallery-member_company">Bill and Melinda Gates Found</div>
        <div class="gallery-company_location">Nashville, TN 28277
          <br>United States</div>
      </div>
      <div class="person-info-wrap" style="opacity: 1;">
        <div class="person-info">
          <h3>Active committees</h3>
          <ul class="subList">
            <li class="subList-item"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have the first 2 divs floating to the left and then the 3rd element is set to **block** and clearing left. The result I'm trying to achieve is so that if the text expands in the 2nd child element the parent container ( **lightbox-item**) should expand as well.

**THE REAL ISSUE**

Sorry, I don't believe I made my problem clear. The second child element(**infoBox**) floats to the next line when the viewport size decrease below **768px** I believe. The parent element expands as expect if viewport size is greater than ~768px.

Comment: What layout do you want at `<768px`? Do you want each div stacked on top?

Comment: Yes so. I ONLY want the divs stack when the viewport width is less than 414px and in portrait. IF the viewport is in landscape and greater than or equal to 568px then display the first 2 child elements inline

Comment: Would you be open to using a different layout, such as flexbox?

Comment: No. Not at this point. But I did think about it

Comment: HTML code provided was the minimum. CSS could have used some trimming since some of the code is font styling. I'll make the edit to reduce the amount of CSS that does not pertain to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must use CSS Media Query to write a specific CSS for a special size
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .lightbox-item {
      z-index: 8200;
      top: 50vh;
      left: 50vw;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      background: #fff;
      position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<div class="lightbox-item" style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -224.5, -226);">
       <div class="avatarBox"></div>
        <div class="infoBox">
          <h2 class="gallery-member_fullname">Bill Gates</h2>
          <div class="gallery-member_title">Founder</div>
          <div class="gallery-member_company">Bill and Melinda Gates Found</div>
          <div class="gallery-company_location">Nashville, TN 28277<br>United States</div>
        </div>
        <div class="person-info-wrap" style="opacity: 1;">
          <div class="person-info">
            <h3>Active committees</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Soooooo....

After some tinkering and 2 cups of coffee later. I changed the parent div from **display: inline-block** to **display: inline-table** See the change below.

```
.lightbox-item {
  z-index: 8200;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-table;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}
```

AND Voila!

My lightbox works as I am expecting. I have other media queries to handle how the children divs stack on mobile.

I'm still open to other suggestions but this solved my problem the quickest without having to resort to restructuring the layout ( FlexBox).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question at all now... is this not the same result?

Comment: I updated my OP with a reduced amount of code to help with readability.