# Second floating child element aligns to next row of parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resolve an issue I'm running into. I have a parent div with 3 floating children. I posted a previous question but that only partially resolved my problem.  [SEE HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314147/div-floats-to-next-line) to reference.

So The problem is that the second child div's width is not known. The 1st and 2nd child div have fixed widths.

The 1st and 2nd child have fixed heights.

The 3rd Child div is set to **display: block !important; clear: both; width: 100%;** so that it goes to the next row and takes up the entire space of the parent div.

The issue is with the 2nd Child element. Since the width is not known and can change dynamically.

What I am trying to achieve is so that the 2nd child div expands horizontally but remains in line with the 1st child div.

**In reference to my previous question. Using *display: inline-table;* does not allow the content to scroll if it overflows.**

```css
.container {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding:5px;
}
.floating-box {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.floating-box2 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.floating-box3 {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0;
  background: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box2">Floating box Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus necessitatibus adipisci quisquam ducimus dolor fugit, officia perferendis harum temporibus laborum iure numquam, assumenda dignissimos neque, quod doloribus nihil autem dolores!</div>
  <div class="floating-box3">Floating box</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/L6ojt8vs/)

Comment: _So The problem is that the second child div's width is not known. The 1st and 2nd child div have fixed widths._

Comment: The 1st and 2nd child divs have fixed Heights.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**, if I understand you correctly and this is what you want:

```css
/* reset browser defaults */
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

.flex-container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items inline by default */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables wrapping */
}

.flex-container > div {border:1px solid}

.one {
  flex: 0 0 200px; /* fixed width / adjust to your needs */
}

.two {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px); /* -200px of the .one fixed width */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.three {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 200px); /* -200px of the .one fixed width */
}

.one, .two {height:100px} /* adjust to your needs / can also use just .one or just .two */
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2
    ..........fake content..........
  </div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. The issue I have with your solution is that I'm trying to "shrink-wrap" the 2nd child div. So that the parent "container" expands and contracts with the dimensions of the children divs.

Comment: @VXp4 No. Sorry for any confusion. I DON'T want the 2nd child to appear on its own line. regardless of its size.

Comment: In your solution. The 2nd child div is taking the remaining space but there isn't much content inside the 2nd child div and yet it extends so much. This is the issue I am having. The 2nd child div should ONLY extend based on the content. Does this help clarify.

Comment: @cpt-crunchy Updated, try it now.

Comment: Last item would be handling the 3rd child so that it doesn't stick out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @VXp. I referenced a CodePen and fiddled around with the flexbox. This is very close to the end result I'm trying to achieve.

```css
    body {
      padding: 2em; 
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: flex;  
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .wrapper > * {
      padding: 10px;
      flex: 1 100%;
    }

    .aside-1 {
      background: gold;
      flex: 1 auto;
      height: 155px;
      max-width: 155px;
    }

    .main {
      text-align: left;
      background: deepskyblue;
      flex: 3 0px;
      order: 2;
      height: 155px;
    }

    .footer {
      background: lightgreen;
      order: 3;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
      <article class="main">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
      </article>
      <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: I still would not accept my answer because the parent div width is based on the "flex" of the viewport and not the children or "content" size.

Comment: You said that you don't want for the 2nd child to stretch to fill the remaining space but you'r doing just that.

Comment: Yes. I realized this. However, the 3rd child element is displaying the way i'm expecting. Like I said in my previous comment, I would not accept my answer.

Comment: This is what I had before. :)

Comment: Perhaps I was looking at your answer prematurely. The issue I was having with it visually, was that the 3rd child element was "sticking" out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160035/discussion-between-cpt-crunchy-and-vxp).